# wpf datagrid :replace tab navigation with enter key

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a requirement I want to replace the tab navigation by enter key navigation on the datagrid .Currently when tab key press on the datagrid the  focus is moved to next cell on the datagrid.Now I want to move to next cell when enter key presses and if the cell is read only false then make it editable and retain focus on the cell .How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Read This may be Help full

[Moving to next control on Enter keypress in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203329/moving-to-next-control-on-enter-keypress-in-wpf)

...

[WPF Tab Key Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547437/wpf-tab-key-navigation)

...

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/tab-navigation-datagrid-210047.aspx

.....

https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/send-key-tab-datagrid-edit-cell-press-154843.aspx