# Moving to next control on button click in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to move to the next control when I click the button instead of the Tab key in a WPF MVVM application. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The usual etiquette is to show that you have either written some code or if this is not possible, demonstrate that you have put some research effort into finding a solution yourself prior to asking for help.

Comment: while clicking the search button I'm creating 3 dynamic textbox using itemscontrol. now I want focus the first textbox on search button click

Comment: Give examples or something you have tried. This will make us understand what you really want to do and what you have tried. This question seems incomplete but you can set focus on the control. This can be achieved by using the Id of the control you want to set focus on.

Answer (score 0):

You question seems not clear. But to set focus on a control you can do this
`controlId.focus()`

However, check out [Moving to next control on Enter keypress in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203329/moving-to-next-control-on-enter-keypress-in-wpf?rq=1), it could be of help too