# Navigate through WPF combobox using up / down arrow keys from the keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Is there a way to navigate through a `ComboBox` elements when dropped down using arrow keys ? 
I am searching through items from an SQL server and they are displayed but I want to traverse through them using the keyboard instead of the mouse.
I tried something like that but it didn't work :

```
private void StackPanel_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        ComboBox = e.Source as ComboBox;
        if (s != null)
        {
            s.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest( FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Xaml :     `<ComboBox1 PreviewKeyDown="StackPanel_PreviewKeyDown" />`

Code source from : [Moving to next control on Enter keypress in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203329/moving-to-next-control-on-enter-keypress-in-wpf)

Here is the combobox : 
[image]

A minor detail, also is there away to remove the highlight from the typed letter ? In this case the letter "e" as displayed in the screen shot.
Thank you so much in advanced I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Shouldn't that be the default behavior of a `ComboBox`?

Comment: no, whenever I click the down arrow it automatically selects the first element and all the other elements disappear

Comment: Did you apply a custom `Style` or `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: no I didn't, could you please tell me how, if that helps ?

Comment: Sorry. I cannot reproduce your issue. Maybe some XAML might help

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly fine the mistake was once I click the down/up arrow key the focus is set to the next/previous item and displays its values that's why it disregards the other, it's like once you set focus on the item as if you selected it !